# How to capture #define in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I am trying to create a quick language parser in Ruby. The entire thing works, and I can successfully run code in my new language, but I couldn't get **#define** to work. I'd like **#define** to be the keyword for creating functions in my weird temporary language.

So far, I've used Regular Expressions to tokenize my code, and from there I'd parse it, translate to JavaScript, and pipe it into node.

The regex I've tried was `/\b\#define\b/`.

Any idea as to why this doesn't work?

PS. This is for my own entertainment, I am not trying to make an efficient parser.

Comment: Try removing the first word boundary?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, that does seem to work. Added a \A and a capture group to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `\b` at the start of the pattern:

```
#define\b
```

or replace the `\b` with `\B`:

```
\B#define\b
```

Your original regex will match `#define` when there are word characters before the `#`:

```
some word#define
```

A word boundary is basically a word character, followed by a non-word character, or vice versa, isn't it?

I think what you want to do is not match `#define` if there are word characters before the `#`, so I suggested to use `\B`.

Alternatively, if you want to match `#define` at the start of the line, use `^` and turn the multiline option on.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding \A instead of \b, and added capture group to fit my needs.